# What's the best way to integrate Tailwindcss Heroicions into Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-blade, tailwind-css, heroicons

What's the best way to integrate Tailwindcss Heroicions into Laravel 9?

This is my workflow. I created a "symbols" folder in my Laravel file structure:

`resources` > `views` > `components` > `symbols`

Then I download and save each SVG file: `arrow-down.blade.php`.

In the SVG blade file I empty the `class` attribute and replace it with `{{ $class }}`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="{{ $class }}">
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6.75 12a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0zM12.75 12a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0zM18.75 12a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0z" />
</svg>
```

And integrate it like this:

```
<x-symbols.star class="w-6 h-6"/>
```

Is there a better way? Can I download Heroicons as Blade files so I don't have to do this manual work?

Comment: Maybe you'll be interested in [this](https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-heroicons) package

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for!